# How do I implement a binary morphological image operation that counts for each pixel the number of non-zero 4-neighbors

Tags: python, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I have a binary image in the form of a Numpy 2D integer array.  I want to create another image with values 0-4 denoting how many of each pixel's 4-neighbors are 1-valued.  I was hoping for something in Numpy or SciPy, but anything in Python will be welcomed.

Comment: [scipy.signal.convolve2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) will do it.

Comment: to elaborate: make a 3x3 kernel where those four neighbors are 1, rest 0.